# history API, url fragment, css :target, scroll position

Tags: javascript, css, browser, html5-history

When loading a url having a fragment, like `/help#beer`, the browsers will render the page `/help`, then scroll to the element with id `beer`, and style the element with any css rules on the `:target` selector.

For a single-page app, this works fine on first page load: the client-side router will render the correct content based on the url, and the browser will scroll and style the target.

However when navigating via the history API, it doesn't work: navigating to `/help#beer` with a js router will render the `/help` page, and push state `/help#beer` with the history API. This does not cause the browser to scroll to the id `beer`, or style it.

Is there any solution to this, other than re-implementing the browser features in javascript?

`window.location.hash` can be assigned, which does cause the browser to scroll and style the `:target`. I can push state `/help`, render the page, then assign `window.location.hash` to `#beer`, and the scroll and style will then be correct. However I then have an extra state in the history, so the back button doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Does using location.replace help?  If you are satisfied with your solution _except_ for the extra history entry, perhaps you can replace it?  Check out example #3: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location